# ファイルから4byteの整数を読みだす

Tags: common-lisp

```
(with-open-file (s f :direction :input :element-type 'unsigned-byte)
  (let ((x (make-array 4 :element-type 'unsigned-byte)))
    (read-sequence x s)
    x))
```

このようにファイルから変数xに4byte読みだすことは出来たのですが，それを4byteの整数に変換するにはどうすればよいのでしょうか．
あるいは4byteの整数として直接読み込むことが出来るのでしょうか？

補足：
wavファイルをparseするコードを自分で書こうと思って質問しました。
wavファイルのヘッダ情報はデータサイズがそれぞれ異なるので、どうしたらそれを分解できるかなと思った次第です。

Comment: 最終的に実現したいことの説明がないと、がんばって回答しても回答がぶれてしまうことが多い気がします。  
何を実現されようとしているのかの補足があると助かります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ファイルから 4 バイト(32 ビット)単位で読み込む様にして、`read-byte` で読み出せばよろしいかと思います。

```
(with-open-file (s "file" :direction :input :element-type '(unsigned-byte 32))
                (read-byte s))
```

`element-type` が `'(unsigned-byte 32)` の場合は `unsigned int`、 `'(signed-byte 32)` とすれば `signed int` として扱われる事になります。

例えば、以下の様にしてサンプルデータを作成して、

```
$ perl -e "print pack('L', -10000)" > int.dat
```

SBCL で読み込んでみます。

```
* (with-open-file (s "int.dat" :direction :input :element-type '(signed-byte 32))
                  (read-byte s))
  => -10000

* (with-open-file (s "int.dat" :direction :input :element-type '(unsigned-byte 32))
                  (read-byte s))
  => 4294957296
```

**追記**

Quicklisp に [cl-binary-file](http://quickdocs.org/cl-binary-file/api) という package がありました…。`signed/unsigned`, `little-endian/big-endian` の指定ができるので、こちらの方が良いかもしれません。

```
* (ql:quickload :cl-binary-file-0.4)
* (use-package :binary-file)
* (read-integer (open-binary-stream "int.dat") :bytes 4 :signed t :endianness :little-endian)
  => -10000
* (read-integer (open-binary-stream "int.dat") :bytes 4 :signed nil :endianness :little-endian)
  => 4294957296
```

※ SBCL では `sb-c:*backend-byte-order*` でシステムの byte order を取得できます。

```
* sb-c:*backend-byte-order*

:LITTLE-ENDIAN
```

**追記その2**

> 同じファイルから4byteの整数以外にバイト列(unsigned-byte 8)も取得したい場合、element-typeを切り替えながら読み込むということは可能なのでしょうか？

はい、以下の様に `with-open-file` を2重にします。

```
(with-open-file (s "int.dat" :direction :input :element-type 'unsigned-byte)
  (with-open-file (int32 "int.dat" :direction :input :element-type '(signed-byte 32))
                  (let ((x (make-array 4 :element-type 'unsigned-byte)))
                    (read-sequence x s)
                    (list x (read-byte int32)))))

=> (#(240 216 255 255) -10000)
```

Comment: 素朴な疑問ですが endianess が違う場合はどうすればかっこいいでしょう？

Comment: @774RR はい、byte order の事を忘れていました。かっこいい？方法を考えてみます

Comment: 同じファイルから4byteの整数以外にバイト列(unsigned-byte 8)も取得したい場合、element-typeを切り替えながら読み込むということは可能なのでしょうか？

Comment: @tamamu 回答に追記しました。

Answer (score 1):

- オクテット(unsigned-byte 8)を読み出す
- 4オクテット単位でまとめたい(unsigned-byte 32として読む)
- 途中でub8<=>ub32を切り替える(且つ切り換え場所から読み込み)

となると [nibbles](http://quickdocs.org/nibbles/) を使うのが簡単かなと思います。    
ライブラリを使わないのならば、オクテットで読み出してエンディアンを考慮しつつ合成するか、ub32で読んでエンディアンを考慮しつつ分解するか、かなと思います。

```
(ql:quickload :nibbles)

;; ファイル作成
(with-open-file (out "/tmp/foo.bin" 
                     :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8) 
                     :direction :output
                     :if-does-not-exist :create
                     :if-exists :supersede)
  (dotimes (i 32)
    (write-byte 255 out)
    (write-byte 0 out)))


;; 読み出し
(with-open-file (in "/tmp/foo.bin" :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
  (let ((ans (list (nibbles:read-ub32/be in) ;unsigned-byte 32/big endian
                   (nibbles:read-ub32/le in) ;unsigned-byte 32/little endian
                   (read-byte in) ;unsigned-byte 8
                   (read-byte in) ;unsigned-byte 8
                   (read-byte in) ;unsigned-byte 8
                   (read-byte in) ;unsigned-byte 8
                   )))
    (format T "~&~{~12D: ~:*#b~32,'0B~%~}" ans)))
;>>  4278255360: #b11111111000000001111111100000000
;>>    16711935: #b00000000111111110000000011111111
;>>         255: #b00000000000000000000000011111111
;>>           0: #b00000000000000000000000000000000
;>>         255: #b00000000000000000000000011111111
;>>           0: #b00000000000000000000000000000000
;=> nil
```